# Getting the value of an item in a django template for loop

Tags: django, forms, django-models, django-templates

Using django, I have a form in which a user enters his `'position'`. The user may add multiple positions. The user may also delete positions. There are two things worth noting with this:

1) in the form, there are two buttons, `'Add'` and `'Delete'`.

2) I am using a for loop in the template to populate the list of positions and delete buttons.

This is what I currently have:

```
# in template
<tr>
    <td>Position</td>
    <td>{{ form.position }} 
        <input type="submit" value="Add" , name='action'/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td>
        {% for position in positions %}
            {{ position}}
            <input type="submit" value="Delete {{position }}", name='action'/> 
        {% endfor %}
    </td>
</tr>

# in views.py
    ...
    if action == 'Add':
        positions.append(request.POST['position'])
        return render_to_response(...)
    if 'Delete' in action:
        positions.remove(request.POST['action'][7:])
        return render_to_response('...)
```

This seems like a very inelegant way to do the "Deletion" part.

Is there a better way to get the value of the `position`, without having to cram in additional information in the `'Delete' submit button`, and then slicing it off to get its value?

Answer (score 2):

I see three options here:

1. Use checkbox field for each position and one "Delete" button. In that case a user can choose multiple positions to be deleted and you can get their IDs from request easily.
2. Use a hidden field `position` and a little bit of Javascript to fill it. If you use jquery it could be:

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="position" value="" />

   {% for position in positions %}
     <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="action" data-position="{{ position }}" />;
   {% endfor %}

   <script type="text/javascript">
      var $position_input = $("input[name='position']");
      $("input[name='action'][value='Delete'].click(function(e) {
         var $this = $(this);
         var position = $this.data("position");
         $position_input.val(position);
      });
   </script>
   ```
3. Insert position ID into name attribute, like this:

   ```
   <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete-position.{{ position }} />
   ```

   In view function you'll have to look through all data in `request.POST` and find all items which start with `delete-position` and then use slicing.